# Upgrading Java project from PDFBox 1.7.0 to 2.0.1

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to update my current java project from **pdfbox 1.7.0** to **2.0.1**. But while doing this upgrade I am facing two issues. Can someone please help me out with the below two questions.

1. **PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments()** this method is deprecated. So considering the best practices I am trying to use **mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting memUsageSetting)** method but I am not sure which memory usage setting that I should use *setupMainMemoryOnly* or *setupTempFileOnly*. My application is running on **Oracle Weblogic server** where there are several scenarios we use this merging pdf feature in our application.
2. We were catching **COSVisitorException** when using the 1.7.0. If I am using 2.0.1 do I need to catch some equivalent exception for **COSVisitorException**.
   However I am having my custom exceptions and **IOException** in my catch block.

Comment: **1)** It depends on your use case. Consider how often do you merge how many how big files and how much memory is available to your application. **2)** As `COSVisitorException` is not part of PDFBox anymore, there is no need to fetch it. If you want to play it safe, catch `Exception`, otherwise assume any structural PDF problem (which formerly caused a `COSVisitorException`) now throws an `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks.. Right now I am not sure about how much memory is allocated for my application (I will have to check this) but this merging will happen 10-15 times max per day and roughly 1-5 pages of pdfs we are trying to merge. Which option will be best advice.

Comment: *10-15 times max per day and roughly 1-5 pages of pdfs* - Unless those PDFs are **very** heavy on graphics and unless your application is allocated only a most meager part of the memory, I would assume a `MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly` variety would suit your requirements.